# NE555 above 100kHz frequency problem

Tags: 555

At first I searched this problem and could not find anything with this specific.

I am using NE555 to generate frequencies. I'm using the calculations of this [website](http://www.ohmslawcalculator.com/555-astable-calculator). I am using 10nf as it says. My problem is I can't generate frequencies above the 100kHz.

I am using 0.1uF as C, 47ohm for both R1 and R2. According to the website, it should give 102kHz but NE555 does not give that. I measured it with an oscilloscope and it just shows noise. I searched [datasheet][3] and find out that NE555 should reach almost 1mHz.

What do you think my problem is? How can I solve it and reach the signals above 100kHz?

[image]

Comment: Either you've got a faulty chip or you've connected it incorrectly. (1) Post a schematic of your setup including supply voltage. (2) Post a photo and someone may spot the problem..

Comment: I'm using the schematic, which shown in website, I am supplying +5V DC from Raspberry, and I build circuit several times but it did not change a thing. I will post a photo when I am available.

Comment: Where did you buy the NE555 from?

Comment: Embed the schematic in your post. The questions and answers on this site should stand on their own when the linked site dies. It also saves us looking it up.

Comment: I bought them from my local electronic-components seller website.

Comment: You're asking pin 7 to sink **a lot of current** when R1,R2 are 47 ohms. Try R1=R2=470 ohms, with 0.01uF at pin 2,6.

Comment: **according to the 555 data sheet**', the periods and delays are accurately calculable when R1 and R2 >= 2kohms, 47ohms is far too low.

Comment: Replace it with a cmos 555 (typical max f - 3MHz)

Comment: I fixed the problem by replacing resistors with higher and capacitor with lower values. Now 555 gives almost 800kHz. Thank you all for trying to help me.

Comment: HVK, can you please mark one of the answers as the correct? If you won't then in 2 years this question will pop up by this websites robot. And then people will try to answer this old question, which is already answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Texas Instruments "NE555" recommended R values are  1k ohms and more,
and 1 MHz operation of that part is not guaranteed.   100kHz is the recommendation.   [NE555 datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ne555.pdf)

More modern variant designs can handle 1 MHz easily, including (again, from Texas Instruments) TLC555 [TLC555 datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tlc555.pdf)
and THAT datasheet explicitly notes discharge internal resistance (about 20 ohms) meaning that R1 and R2 ought to be much higher (4k ohms would be good).

Answer (score 1):

> What do you think my problem is?

not all 555s are equal and some of them cannot go that high.

if you have to go that high, look for a part that does that. All connect the capacitor to the output pin and use a low value resistor.

there are other ways, often simpler, to get you there.

edit: I put together a little routine quickly, to demonstrate the concept.

```
 //measure rc time to charge to '1' on RC_READ pin
uint32_t rctmr_get(uint8_t ch_pin) {
    uint32_t tmp;
    IO_IN(RC_DDR, ch_pin);                  //discharge. ch_pin idles high/input
    IO_OUT(RC_DDR, RC_READ);                //discharges the capacitor (RC_READ idles low/output)
    while (IO_GET(RC_PORTIN, RC_READ)) continue;    //until the capacitor is fully discharged
    IO_OUT(RC_PORT, ch_pin);                //start to charge through the ch_pin
    IO_IN(RC_DDR, RC_READ);                 //start to charge up the capacitor
    tmp = ticks();                          //time stamp tmp
    while (IO_GET(RC_PORTIN, RC_READ)==0) continue; //wait for READ pin to go high
    tmp = ticks() - tmp;                    //measure the time elapsed
    IO_OUT(RC_DDR, RC_READ);                //discharge the capacitor
    IO_IN(RC_DDR, ch_pin);                  //start to discharge from the charge pin (idles high / input)
    return tmp;
}
```

On a 16Mhz PIC16F1936 @2.5v, 100K resistor, I got a count of 183xx for a 104 capacitor - the last two digits vary a little.

1. a 472 capacitor got a reading of 775 - 777. So fairly good linearity.

With a little bit of filtering, you should get smoother results.

So it has a range of up to 2^32/18350*0.1u = 24F, and a resolution of 5.5pf. With different resistors used in charging the capacitor, you can expand that range further.

the code is fairly portable and should be able to run on pretty much any mcu.

Comment: To be more specific I am just trying to create this frequency for test purposes. In my real project, I will not know the capacitance value of the C at the circuit. I will connect a sensor at there, which will act as a capacitance. I will measure frequency with a microprocessor and by knowing the precise value of the resistance I will calculate the capacitance. So there should be no other component at the output pin.

Comment: if you are using a mcu, it can do this without a 555, over a much wider range.

Comment: I know but I also need to have a frequency value. I should calculate both of them with 555. That is my task. But thank you for the 'not equal' advice. I will search that.

Comment: Two suggestions: a NAND or NOT gate would be a much better oscillator than a 555 here.

Comment: if you are thinking about using the frequency as a proxy for the capacitance, you will find that the frequency from such an oscillator varies significantly.

Comment: a much better approach is to charge up the capacitor through a CCS and measure the rise time. you can use different CCS to cover a wide range of capacitance. This can be done very easily through a mcu.

Comment: is **CCS** something that is widely known / common knowledge? I get **C**arbon **C**apture and **S**torage, **C**ombined **C**harging **S**ystem, when I google "CCS electric". The other thing I can come up with on my own is **C**urrent **C**ontrolled **S**ource.

Comment: @HarrySvensson: controlled current source.  Q = CV; so you can force some known amount of charge in and measure the voltage rise to calculate cap.

Comment: **C**ontrolled **C**urrent **S**ource makes more sense.